# Can I grep only the first n lines of a file?

Tags: bash, search, grep

I have very long log files, is it possible to ask grep to only search the first 10 lines?

Answer (score 221, accepted):

The magic of pipes;

```
head -10 log.txt | grep <whatever>
```

Comment: you can also pipe an arbitrary stream to `head`: `someCmd | head -10 `

Comment: Head defaults to printing the first 10 lines to standard output, so this is valid for 10 lines `head log.txt | grep <whatever>`

Comment: Is there a way to do this when using grep's `-l` option?  I'd like to list all the files who's first 5 characters are `RIFFD`.

Answer (score 63):

For folks who find this on Google, I needed to search the first `n` lines of multiple files, but to only print the matching filenames.  I used

```
gawk 'FNR>10 {nextfile} /pattern/ { print FILENAME ; nextfile }' filenames
```

The `FNR..nextfile` stops processing a file once 10 lines have been seen.  The `//..{}` prints the filename and moves on whenever the first match in a given file shows up.  To quote the filenames for the benefit of other programs, use

```
gawk 'FNR>10 {nextfile} /pattern/ { print "\"" FILENAME "\"" ; nextfile }' filenames
```

Comment: I was one of those folks who found this on Google. Thanks!

Comment: for me, this code printed out the full path of the file.  Which is exactly what I needed.  Also `FNR=1` will just search 1st line.  Thanks!

Comment: To do this recursively over a directory: `find ./path -type -f -exec awk 'FNR>10 {nextfile} /pattern/ { print FILENAME ; nextfile }' '{}' +`

Comment: Thanks @OrangeDog. One slight correction: should be `-type f`

Comment: Just what I was searching for!

Answer (score 28):

Or use `awk` for a single process without `|`:

```
awk '/your_regexp/ && NR < 11' INPUTFILE
```

On each line, if `your_regexp` matches, and the number of records (lines) is less than 11, it executes the default action (which is printing the input line).

Or use `sed`:

```
sed -n '/your_regexp/p;10q' INPUTFILE
```

Checks your regexp and prints the line (`-n` means don't print the input, which is otherwise the default), and quits right after the 10th line.

Comment: Why not quit on the 10th? (see sed solution)

Comment: `awk '{ if ( NR <= 10 ) { if(index($0,"ab") > 0) { print $0; } } else { exit; } }' textfile` -- faster.

Comment: @potong you are right, corrected.
@srikanthradix while it can be faster you're solution is not searching for regexps but only for fixed strings. `awk '{ if ( NR <= 10 ) { if(  $0 ~ "YOUR_REGEXP") { print } } else { exit; } }' textfile` does.

Comment: Plus the style isn't `awkish`. `2xifs` and `1xelse` in a command that needs no action statement would make aho. weinberger and kernighan cry ...

Comment: I think, instead of NR it would be better to use FNR, because if you use awk with multiple files FNR starts from 0 for each file.

Answer (score 10):

You have a few options using programs along with `grep`. The simplest in my opinion is to use `head`:

```
head -n10 filename | grep ...
```

`head` will output the first 10 lines (using the `-n` option), and then you can pipe that output to `grep`.

Comment: I didn't even realize, all the solutions here using `head` have used `-n 10` **(including me)** not realizing that `head` by **default** displays ***only 10 lines***. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
grep "pattern" <(head -n 10 filename)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
head -10 log.txt | grep -A 2 -B 2 pattern_to_search
```

`-A 2`: print two lines before the pattern.

`-B 2`: print two lines after the pattern.

```
head -10 log.txt # read the first 10 lines of the file.
```

Comment: If I recall, `-C 2` will do the same as `-A 2 -B 2`

Answer (score 3):

The output of `head -10 file` can be piped to `grep` in order to accomplish this:

```
head -10 file | grep …
```

Using Perl:

```
perl -ne 'last if $. > 10; print if /pattern/' file
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following line:

```
head -n 10 /path/to/file | grep [...]
```

Answer (score 3):

An extension to Joachim Isaksson's answer: Quite often I need something from the middle of a long file, e.g. lines 5001 to 5020, in which case you can combine `head` with `tail`:

```
head -5020 file.txt | tail -20 | grep x
```

This gets the first 5020 lines, then shows only the last 20 of those, then pipes everything to grep.

(Edited: fencepost error in my example numbers, added pipe to grep)

Answer (score 0):

grep -A 10 <Pattern>

This is to grab the pattern and the next 10 lines after the pattern. This would work well only for a known pattern, if you don't have a known pattern use the "head" suggestions.

Comment: Although it might right. add more description of question to make answer more comprehensive.

Comment: This answers a completely different question and is not useful in this context.

Answer (score -3):

```
grep -m6 "string" cov.txt
```

This searches only the first 6 lines for `string`

Comment: No, this will give you the first 6 occurrences of "string" in the whole cov.txt file