# How to conditionally edit files in vim

Tags: vim

I have a requirement to batch edit a bunch of files using vim based on their content. The simplest example is that I'd like to perform a series of let's say substitutions on files but only if the first line of the file matches a certain pattern.

I'm trying to do this kind of thing:

```
vim -e -s $file < changes.vim
```

I should add that I have no access to tools like sed and awk and would like to perform the entire operation in vim.

Comment: if I were you, I will go for `awk/sed`

Comment: Kent is right, what changes would you like to make on those files? Likely that there's an easier way with [tag:sed] or [tag:awk].

Comment: Can you show us the contents of the `changes.vim` file? Most likely that is what needs changing in order to solve this problem without the use of external tools.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a `vim-only` solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you find the list of files you need, and pass that list into the command you want.  For this, a combination of `awk` and `xargs` would seem useful. There are probably clever shorter things you can do…

```
awk 'FNR>1 {nextfile} /pattern/ { print FILENAME ; nextfile }' filePattern | xargs -I{} vim -e -s {} < changes.vim
```

In the above, `filePattern` gives all the files you want (maybe `*.c`), `/pattern/` is the regex of the match you are looking for. `xargs` will take "one output at a time" and substitute it into the following command at the place where I put the `{}`.

I want to give a tip of the hat to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19692362/1967396) where I found the inspiration for this answer.

## vim only solution

**EDIT** - after I posted this you said you need a "vim only" solution. Here it is…

Step 1: create a `conditionalEdits.vim` file with the following lines at the start:

```
let line_num = search('searchExpression')  " any regex 
if line_num == 1                           " first line matched
  center                                   " put your editing commands here...
  update                                   " save changes
endif
quit
```

Of course, instead of just centering the first line, you will want to put all your editing commands inside the `if` statement.

Now, you execute this command with

```
vim -c '/path/to/my/conditionalEdits.vim' -s filePattern
```

where `filePattern` matches all the files you *might* be interested in (but you will know for sure after you have looked at line 1 inside…)

Obviously you can navigate through the file in the usual way and look for matches / patterns etc to your heart's content - but this is the basic idea.

Helpful links: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-vim-script-1/
and http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com

I **highly** recommend that you do this in a separate directory, using copies of a handful of files first, to make sure this actually does what you think it does. I would hate to be responsible for a bunch of files being overwritten (you do back up, right?)

Comment: @Kent I'm pretty sure - and it might be a better solution. But that wasn't the question. I don't know what is in `changes.vim` so I chose to answer the question whilst staying as close as possible to the initial intent.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over all files, if you find the pattern, open vim. Once it is modified to your needs and closed, the next one will open.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for file in *; do
    if [[ "$(sed '1q' ${file})" == "pattern" ]]; then
        vim ${file}
    fi
done
```

Comment: This solution has the advantage of clarity over cleverness.

Comment: Both valid responses, but my requirement is to do this without access to tools like sed and awk and do the whole operation in vim.

Answer (score 0):

Within Vim, you can determine the matching files via `:vimgrep`; to check for a match in the first line, the `\%l` atom is handy:

```
:vimgrep /\%1lcertain pattern/ {file-glob}
```

Then, you can iterate through all matches with `:cfnext`, or use the `:QFDo` command from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5686810/813602).

You can pass those commands either via `vim -c {cmd} -c {cmd} ...`, or in a separate script, as you outline in your question.

Comment: Could you expand this into a complete solution? If you do I might just prefer it over my own...